# Use a module as library IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-module

Good evening, I want to use a module as a library on my project. For that I followed some instructions given on some similar questions but with no effect

I'll try to describe my problem as clear as possible.

[image]

I have my main project named oncofinder with 2 modules created: oncofinder-gui and oncofinder-core. Let's say I want to import the core model on the gui, like this:

```
import oncofinder.lib.common;
```

And I want to declare it like this:

```
package oncofinder.lib.common;
```

On the SimpleThreadFactory java class. For that, I would like that the path to be:

```
oncofinder/oncofinder-core/src/main/java/oncofinder/lib/common/SimpleThreadFactory.java
```

I already tried to create the library and add it as a dependency as you can see in the follow images:

[image]

[image]

However, I still get the error:

```
Package name 'oncofinder.lib.common' does not correspond to the file path '
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and if there is an easier way to import my Modules as dependecies?

Kind Regards

Comment: IntelliJ has a nice autocomplete feature where you start typing the class name that you want to use and, if you push enter, it will import the correct package and finish the name for you. Might not work but you could try just typing in SimpleThreadFactory in the class you need to use it

Comment: according to your first screenshot, the class `SimpleThreadFactory` resides in something named "common library root"; if that is a real directory name under `src/main/java` (which I suppose), you should change it to `onconfinder/lib/common` to resolve the package file path problem

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't thinking straight. Thank you!